# Pausing Android timer running in activity

Tags: android

I have a timer running in my activity. Let's say user switches to another activity. Should i pause my timer in that case' because sometimes my whole activity gets killed when i resume my application?

Comment: [SERVICE.........](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html)

Comment: Actually i need to show timer in my application and the current location, so I don't think service would sufice and it's not doing any heavy tasks , it just updates the timer and the correct location

Comment: But you need something to keep it running and (a process) that should not be killed...and service fulfils your requirements

Comment: a Service could also be killed, for example if not enough memory is available. To set the service on foreground is a little bit safer..

Answer (score 0):

Hold your timer remaining time/value/etc into a  global static object. When you switch back, use it for your timer  or design a good application lifecycle with onPause, onResume  etc.